# Command line pass generic arguments to an Intent

Tags: android, android-studio

I apologize in advance, I'm having difficulty understanding my task, and wording it. I want to be able to start an activity from the command line while passing it generic arguments. My boss said that we don't yet know what is going to be passed in, so it needs to be generic. I can make it so an Intent object takes for instance a string, or an int, or whatever -- I know how to do that, but how do I make it just take some generic argument(s)?

Comment: "start an activity from the command line" -- I am interpreting this as: "use `adb shell am start` to start an activity from the command line of a developer machine". "while passing it generic arguments" -- I am interpreting "arguments" as referring to `Intent` extras. "but how do I make it just take some generic argument(s)?" -- from the standpoint of data types, you cannot have "generic arguments". The switches for `adb shell am start` for specifying the extras require that you indicate the data type.

Comment: You are correct in your assumptions. I am using adb shell am start... Thank you for letting me know it cannot take generic arguments as you have to indicate the data type. I might just have to talk to my boss and see what he wants. The problem is, is that his people don't know what arguments are going to be passed in so he said to try to make it generic but it might not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that you want a way to develop your code without have the right information for your intent. In that case just use an already defined item, string, object, whatever you want to get in your activity from an intent. For example:

```
    public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    //values that you are going to use
    private boolean mIsVideo;
    private String mFilePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_awesome_layout);

        // get extra parameters from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
       //We don't have an intent yet, so just add a defined value to your parameters and still working     
        //mIsPhoto = intent.getBooleanExtra("is-photo-key");
        //mFilePath = intent.getStringExtra("file-path-key");
        mIsPhoto = true;
        mFilePath = "storage/emulated/DCIM/Camera/myExamepleImage.jpeg";

        //All your code
    }
```

I think that this is what are you looking for. Usually you will not have the information or original values at the beginning of a project. So usually you are going to work with defined values. For example in this case, this is the code for a `VideoMediaPlayer`.

I don't have my video files values or anything that I can get from and intent. So I will work with the same path (and same video) until I will be able to get the right values.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but I don't understand what was the point of getting the intent if you're not using it. Also I'm assuming that mIsPhoto is supposed to be the instance variable mIsVideo. To be entirely honest, I just don't exactly understand what my task is, so I'm going to ask my boss to re explain it to me.

Comment: I'm using and intent cause you say that you will use it in the future. You can delete the line and use it when your boss will let you know the information that your activity will recieve. its just and example. Later in my code i use mIsPhoto to set and imageView if the media file that I recieve is a photo or call a new video Surface if the file is a video.